# Why does Android Studio have an internal error after installing

Tags: java, android-studio

I just downloaded and installed Android Studio. I've tried running it, but there's some internal error. I've tried uninstalling, deleting the JDK, and reinstalling, but I'm still having this same problem. I also tried to download the new installer and install it again but same problem happened.

Here's the error:

```
java.util.concurrent.CompletionExecption:org.picocontainer.PicoRegistrationException:Keyio.flutter.settings.FlutterSettings duplicated 

at java.base/util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:314) 

at...(many more errors)

at...(many more errors)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I will like to know which OS you are on. **But try this**;

If you have **anti-virus**, you want to disable it till after a successful installation because some anti-virus delete some files at installation time because those files are read as treat to your PC.

Comment: I'm using Windows 10. Already disable my antivirus sir, i watched youtube also for the solution but still can't resolve it.

Comment: Did you delete the entire android studio folder?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on MacOS ,then try deleting the marketplace directory which contains plugins.

```
rm -Rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/AndroidStudio2020.3.1/marketplace/
```

or

```
~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio202.3.1/plugins
```

There can be `Android Studio` under `Application Support` but that is not the correct one.

If you use Windows then , try the following ways:-

1. Changing these lines of code

Open the folder where you installed Android Studio:

ex: C:Program FilesAndroidAndroid Studiobin

Find and edit idea.properties. You can edit this with use notepad++ or
any similar application that allows text editing.

Add this line as the final in the file:

disable.android.first.run=true

Now run Android Studio again.

2. Opening in Offline Mode

Close Android Studio Turn off Internet connection and be sure of it.

Start Android Studio. You will see a popup box with Cancel option in it.

Then Click cancel.

3. Reinstalling JAVA, PYTHON

Downloading new package of ANDRIOD STUDIO and installing it again after deleting all the previous files

4. Adding bin directory to the enviornment variables
   JAVA PYTHON JRE-AndriodStudio
5. Deleting the user plugins that we have in Andriod Studio. [But as its my first time of installation, I am not having them]
6. Even tried restarting my system
7. Closing all other instances running via java, to ensure it not disturbing that particular port number

But no programmes were running in the process that took the use of java

Windows Credits:- https://ittone.ma/ittone/start-failed-fresh-installation-android-studio/